# Using .after() for creating a table but cannot access variable´s value to fill cells

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using .after to add a table to my website but I need values from a variable to be inserted in the cell. It seems like I cannot access them. Possibly I am taking a completely wrong approach.

```
var object0001= {price: 1000, bedrooms:2}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#dot0003").hover(
        function(){

            $("#tablespace").after(
            '<table  border="4">'+
            '<tr><td>price</td>'                '<td>object0001.price</td></tr>'+
            '<tr><td>number of bedrooms</td>'   '<td>object0001.bedrooms</td></tr>'+
            '<tr><td>livingroom</td>'           '<td><img src="_index/_dots/dot.gif" width="20" height="20"></td></tr></table>')        

    });


    });
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this

```
var object0001= {price: 1000, bedrooms:2};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dot0003").hover(function(){
    $("#tablespace").after(
      '<table  border="4">'+
      '<tr><td>price</td><td>'+object0001.price+'</td></tr>'+
      '<tr><td>number of bedrooms</td><td>'+object0001.bedrooms+'</td></tr>'+
      '<tr><td>livingroom</td><td><img src="_index/_dots/dot.gif" width="20" height="20"></td></tr></table>')        
  });
});
```

whatever is between the '' is a string , and not to be parsed as JavaScript

try to make all of the html in a variable , then pass it to append , it will save you time when you try to maintain the code

Comment: Also the strings that appear next to each other without a + between them were causing problems

Comment: Just another quick question. As you can see there is an image in the table. Am I correct that the browser does not load this image until the user actually moves the mouse over "dot0003"? I want to make sure that the website in the initial state loads quickly! thanks

Comment: yeah , thats true .. you will append the image after hover , and right then only it will be loaded .. before that it is just text